# How to send very big amount of data to server using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, server

I am practicing ajax and want to send big amount of data to server (for instance I want to make tags for a post which can be up to 20 tags). Currently all I do is concatenate each tag with specific symbol between them and then in server I filter it and convert it to many tags again but I don't think that's the natural way. So what is the best way to send say, 30 - 40 entries to server with ajax optimally.

UPDATE (As some of the people suggested I am showing js code example):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tagsToSend = "tag1%tag2%tag3%tag4%tag5%tag6%tag7%tag8%tag9%tag10%tag11%tag12%tag13";
     $.ajax({
        url: "test.php", 
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            tags: tagsToSend
        },
        success: function(result){
            alert(result)
        }
    });
})
```

So basically in server I'll just iterate over the given tags string and filter each tag. And I want more natural way.

Comment: You should use JSON.

Comment: @SLaks yeah, but how can I put 40 entries in JSON? (aside from making the whole JSON with hand)

Comment: @Banned: You're looking for `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: 40 entries is not very big.  Unless you have tens of thousands, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Banned 40 entries in a map is pretty tiny. And we can't say how you'll generate it without seeing where the data comes from. Just create it as a normal JS object, and stringify it.

Comment: @SLaks I still don't get it. JSON.stringify converts a json object to a string, but, if I already have json object I will simply put it into jQuery's $ajax data property

Comment: It's a bit hard to say anything without seeing an example, but what's the point of concatenating the tags with a symbol instead of passing them as an array?

Comment: @JJJ Say I have an input field in which the text looks like this: tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 ... tag40. All I want now is to send all those 40 tags to server using ajax. Currently I do the following, I put '%' between them so now I have a big string looking like: tag1%tag2%tag3 ... and I send this big string to server which then iterates and takes each tag. I want more  natural way.

Comment: @Banned [edit] your question and add how you do this. That gives us an insight into how your data is before you concatenate it and allows us to help you better. :)

Comment: @Banned can you also add how you get that `tagsToSend` string? I doubt you add it as a string literal.

Comment: @Ivar you mean how I get it on server or how I get it from input bar?

Comment: How you get it from the input bar. How is it concatinated.

Comment: A more natural way is to use jQuery's serialize() and let jQuery get all your tags for you. Then at the server use a while loop at get the tags as long as there are tags. `$x = 1; while( isset( $_POST['tag' . $x] ) ){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to sending tags **as a json array** and not **GET parameter**. Something like this:

```
var postData = {};
postData['tagsToSend'] = ["tag1", "tag2", ...];
```

And inside your ajax config:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Now, you can get a **json** in your php file and parse it into php array.
This can help you to have **more readable and cleaner** request to the server.

Comment: And instead of data: JSON.stringify(postData) can't I put postData. like this:
$ajax ...,
postData,
...

Comment: @Banned My experience is a limited; however, I'd say it depends on your data. If you have a survey and you want to send it to the server you have two options. Send all the answers through post/get or send an "survey object/array" through post/get. A survey is very object-like so you would probably create an object. Applying this to your case, you have a bunch of similar data, so it is very "array-like" and you should probably send an array through post/get (as hamed is showing here).